# Make UITextView go full screen when clicked from static cell within UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

The ViewController consists of a TableView with static (customised) cells. One of the rows consists of a UITextView which shows 2 lines of text (as preview). When a user clicks on it, it'd open up to a UITextView filling up the full-screen.

```
else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
    static NSString *countryRegionCellID = @"NotesCell";
    NotesCell *cell = (NotesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:countryRegionCellID];
    if (!cell) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:countryRegionCellID owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NotesCell class]]) {
                cell = (NotesCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [self drawBorder:cell];
    [self drawPersonalNotes:cell];
    return cell;
}
```

UITextView delegate calls:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"textViewShouldBeginEditing");
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];    
    CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [textView setFrame:r];
    return YES;
}
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"textViewDidBeginEditing");
}
```

Since the static cell has a defined height of 44, UITextView fills only the cell rather than the full-screen. Do I bring on a new view controller on top of the table view? Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the UITextView? Is the textViewShouldBeginEditing: being called?

Comment: Yes. When the delegate gets called, it brings up a UITextView that fills the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just segue to a new vc that just contains a simple textview however you'd like it to look.

When finished, assign that text to whatever property you would from the tableView by accessing it using the `presentingViewController` property. Good to go.